# New servlet throws javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

Been working on this error for a while now... In netbeans a new servlet created from the Servlet wizard will throw a 500 internal server error. Other times it won't find the server class:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class java.markbratanov.domain.login or a class it depends on
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.markbratanov.domain.login
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

I've rebuilt the project, cleaned it... checked web.xml, still see the same problem.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>accountInformation</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>markbratanov.domain.AccountInformation</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>transferFunds</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>AccountTransfers</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>java.markbratanov.domain.login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>accountInformation</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/accountInformation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>transferFunds</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/transferFunds</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**login.java**

```
package java.markbratanov.domain;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Mark
 */
public class login extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet login</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet login at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

**Package layout:**

[image]

Any help / comments / guidance would be greatly appreciated. I've spent more time debugging project than actually programming the project and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, **never** include *java* as part of the name of your packages. Second, post the kind of request you're firing that makes this exception appear.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ok. will refactor and post the exception. one sec.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Refactored to delete java from the packages. I'm firing a simple get request to the glassfish server: localhost:8080/TitanBank/login

Comment: And you still get the same exception?

Comment: Just rebuilt the project and cleaned up a java.markbratanov in the web.xml, now it fires perfectly.

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **should not** use *java* as part of the name of your packages. **EVER**.

Rename your packages and try again.